# How to create multiple documents in Mongoose in one request

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose, api-design

How would I go about creating multiple documents with different schemas in one REST API request in Node/Mongoose/Express?

Say for example I need to create a user and a site on a single request, say for example `/createUser`.

I could of course create a user and then in the returned promise, create the next record, but what if that second record doesn't meet validation? Then I've created a user without the second record.

```
User.create(userData)
    .then(user => {
        Site.create(siteData)
            .then(site => {
                // Do something
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                // If this fails, I'm left with a user created without
                // a site.
            })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Is there a good practice to follow when creating multiple documents like this? Should I run manual validation instead before each .create() runs? Any guidance/advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the transaction problem here. You are trying to write into two different models but want the whole operation to be atomic and if any of them fails you need to rollback. Up until mongo 4.0 transactions were not supported by mongo and a work around for these sort issues was [two phased commits](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). Now in mongo 4.0 we have [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/) to cater such problems.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Transactions seems exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the hint, didn't realize this existed.

Comment: Happy to help !